# Problem with software updates in 12.04

Tags: updates

Since two weeks ago I can't update my package sources and software in German Ubuntu 12.04.

Running "sudo apt-get update" in my Terminal gives me this message:

```
maximilian@maximilian-Vostro-3700:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                      
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                             
Hole:1 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease [2.979 B]                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease                      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                
Hole:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg [316 B]                    
Hole:3 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]         
Hole:4 http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [72 B]                     
Hole:5 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                         
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable InRelease                                      
Hole:6 http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg [198 B]                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                      
Hole:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release [11,9 kB]                      
Hole:8 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49,6 kB]           
Hole:9 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages [896 B]     
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg                    
Hole:10 http://archive.canonical.com precise Release [7.078 B]                 
Hole:11 http://deb.opera.com stable Release.gpg [189 B]                        
Hole:12 http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release [11,9 kB]                     
Hole:13 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1.338 B]                          
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free TranslationIndex             
Hole:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [198 B]                  
Hole:15 http://packages.medibuntu.org precise InRelease [7.096 B]              
Hole:16 http://deb.opera.com stable Release [632 B]                            
Hole:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources [668 B]                  
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                                  
Hole:18 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [464 B]                 
Hole:19 http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Sources [4.516 B]         
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                          
Hole:20 http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free i386 Packages [773 B]             
Hole:21 http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources [8.023 B]                
Hole:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages [1.045 B]          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hole:23 http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages [6.041 B]   
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                          
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                        
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex              
Hole:24 http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/free Sources [3.348 B]           
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free TranslationIndex                      
Hole:25 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [59,7 kB]     
Hole:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release [49,6 kB]                    
Hole:27 http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages [10,7 kB]          
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hole:28 http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/non-free Sources [4.394 B]       
Hole:29 http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/free i386 Packages [3.243 B]     
Hole:30 http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/non-free i386 Packages [6.643 B] 
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/free TranslationIndex                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                    
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/non-free TranslationIndex            
Hole:31 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [1.950 B]
Hole:32 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [1.382 B]
Hole:33 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [18,9 kB] 
Hole:34 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [221 kB]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex                
Hole:35 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [3.968 B]
Hole:36 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2.392 B]
Hole:37 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [61,1 kB]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex            
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex        
Hole:38 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex [74 B]
Hole:39 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex [71 B]
Hole:40 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex [71 B]
Hole:41 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex [73 B]
Hole:42 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en [104 kB]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex          
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex    
Hole:43 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en [995 B]
Hole:44 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en [978 B]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex      
Hole:45 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en [36,8 kB]
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-de_DE            
Hole:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages [4.796 kB]    
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-de               
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en               
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free Translation-de_DE                     
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-de_DE             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-de_DE                    
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-de_DE                    
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free Translation-de                        
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-de                
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-de_DE                         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-de                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-de                       
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free Translation-en                        
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/free Translation-de_DE               
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/free Translation-de                  
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-de                            
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/free Translation-en                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/non-free Translation-de_DE
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/non-free Translation-de              
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org precise/non-free Translation-en              
Hole:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages [121 kB]    
Hole:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex [2.676 B]
Hole:49 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex [2.922 B]  
Hole:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-de [108 kB]   
Hole:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en [93,4 kB]  
Hole:52 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-de [1.801 kB]   
Hole:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en [3.341 kB]   
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages                
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages                
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources                
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources              
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Fehl http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-de_DE                   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-de                      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-de_DE             
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-de                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-de_DE             
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-de                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-de_DE               
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-de                  
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en                  
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-de_DE           
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-de              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-de_DE     
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-de        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-de_DE     
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-de        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-de_DE       
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-de          
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en          
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-de_DE         
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-de            
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en            
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-de_DE   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-de      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-de_DE   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-de      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-de_DE     
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-de        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en        
Es wurden 11,0 MB in 33 s geholt (323 kB/s)                                    
W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von http://archive.ubuntu.com/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]

E: Manche Indexdateien konnten nicht heruntergeladen werden. Sie wurden ignoriert oder an ihrer Stelle ältere verwendet.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should try changing your software sources.

To do this you can open a terminal `CTRL+ALT+T` and enter `software-properties-gtk` and then select "Main Server" from the dropdown menu pictured below.

[image]

After selecting the main mirror open another terminal and enter `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a bug listing on launchpad a couple days ago and now your problem. However no one seems bearing an idea about this but subscribe and keep watching the report over [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1091317). Someone might release a patch soon.